# Most efficient Rails query method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been looking into a few ways of writing efficient ActiveRecord queries and I thought I might put it out to gather a consensus on who thinks what might be best.

```
@page = @current_shop.pages.where(state: "home").first
```

At the moment, I've surmised that find_by_sql might be the best route?

Comment: Best for what? Does this line generate suboptimal SQL? If so, why do you think that?

Comment: If you want speed, just test both and chose what's best for you. But the benefit on speed will be minimal compared to the drawback of using string sql statements, that's like the whole point of using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

Rails helpfully logs execution time for every query and a query of that form is usually quite simple. It's a dual-condition `SELECT` with a `LIMIT` applied.

`find_by_sql` is reserved for *exceptional* circumstances, not routine ones. In this case if you went the "raw query" route you might save, at best, a fraction of a millisecond. You'll also get back a raw query result, not a model, which you'll then have to do something with.

This is a classic case of premature optimization. If you have a *measurable performance problem*, as opposed to a suspected performance problem, then you might want to consider caching to avoid the database call entirely instead of trying to execute it slightly faster.